# FB4: Safari ignores keyboard, Firefox and Camino don't close window

Tags: flash-builder

I'm having a few problems with Flash Builder 4.

If I use Safari as a debug browser, it simply ignores any keyboard input.

If I instead use Camino or Firefox keyboard works, but it won't close its window automatically when I *Terminate* from Flash Builder (Safari did that).

Any clue?

Comment: @ZJR: chrome has an integrated Flash plugin, it's not suitable for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If your project allows it, try this: Set the wmode parameter to "window" (instead of "opaque" or "transparent"). This is one way of getting around this very annoying Safari 5 bug (which, incidentally, occurs in both Windows and Mac versions of Safari).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a [bug in Safari/Flash Player](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3214512?start=0&tstart=0).  The only solution that seems to be working is setting wmode to something other than `transparent` or `opaque`.

You can enable the debug Flash Player in Chrome by going to `chrome://plugins/`, clicking the +Details link in the top right, and enabling the debug version.